# Problem passing parameters to stored procedure

Tags: mariadb

I don't know how to pass the custom table names (eg `prepAccTN`) so that the SP gets executed w/o `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table '[my-schema-name].prepacctn' doesn't exist`

Tried executing it like so

```
CALL Bill_UpdateUnbalancedPrepaidAccounts('correct_table_name', 'boo', 3);
CALL Bill_UpdateUnbalancedPrepaidAccounts("correct_table_name", 'boo', 3);
CALL Bill_UpdateUnbalancedPrepaidAccounts("my-schema-name.correct_table_name", 'boo', 3);
```

All failed!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Bill_UpdateUnbalancedPrepaidAccounts(prepAccTN VARCHAR(100), wtrTN VARCHAR(100), prepAccId INT)
BEGIN
  UPDATE prepAccTN SET `unbalanced` = (
    SELECT SUM(`chargesecs`) FROM wtrTN WHERE `prepaidaccount` = prepAccId AND `prepaccsettl` = 0
  ) WHERE `id` = prepAccId;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried out the prepared statements but unfortunately they cannot be used within the stored procedure! So I do not use a SP now and put the whole necessary code (back) into the trigger. Not the best and preferred way but it's ok to me and my little sql code I have to execute

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to pass ther table name as a parameter to a stored procedure you need to use [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). You cannot use the parameter directly in a query.